# How to print backslash in single quoted string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following string in ruby version 2.3.3:

```
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01u\x00\x00\x01u\b'
```

I would like to compare it to another string. However, the following occurs:

```
x = '\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01u\x00\x00\x01u\b'
 => "\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1A\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\rIHDR\\x00\\x00\\x01u\\x00\\x00\\x01u\\b"
```

Where the addition of the extra slash messes up the comparison. Equally confusing, the following happens:

```
 x.gsub("\\\\", "\\")
 => "\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1A\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\rIHDR\\x00\\x00\\x01u\\x00\\x00\\x01u\\b"
```

I have tried double quoting the string, using %{} and %Q[]. None of them simply store the string without interpreting escape sequences. How do I store this string without altering it?

Comment: Possibly just compare the bytes. `str.bytes == other.bytes`? This would obviously fail unless they had the same encoding.

Comment: Where does your first string come from? And why does it start with single tick ' instead of double tick " ? That's what's throwing everything off; `'\n'` is two characters; a backslash and an `n`. Only `"\n"` is a real linefeed.

Comment: Your solution works, but as a more general question, how do I print a backslash in ruby?

Comment: @philip its a byte string from a png. I want to compare the beginning of a response that comes back as a hex escaped string. The response is formatted correctly. I can't store the comparison without getting the extra slash.

Comment: That string is impossible to be a byte string from a PNG, because it has literal backslashes in it \. The single tick ' is not escaping the string correctly. Switch your original string to double tick " and it will start working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So long as the strings share the same encoding, byte comparison would be elegant solution without the need for additional escaping.

```
str.bytes == other.bytes
```

To display a backslash, you simply escape it with a single backslash:

```
puts '\\'
\
```

Additionally, depending on your exact usage, could use the `<=>` operator:

```
(str <=> other).zero?
```

**EDIT**

To expand a little more, there is a difference in what is *displayed* to you if you just did something like this:

```
a = '\\'
p a
=> '\\'
```

This will show itself as two backslashes, but it is still in fact a single character, not two.

```
a = '\\'
a.bytes
=> [92] # ASCII code for a backslash (single byte)
```

Comment: yes, but if I store x = '\\' then x contains "\\" not "\"

Comment: Escaping is only necessary when displaying. When storing, just let it be what it is. If I wanted to store a newline in a variable, I would simply store it as `x = '\n'`, not with double slashes.

Comment: x='\' escapes the last quote, I can't store it.

Comment: The whole problem is its not possible to simply store and compare a string with a single slash in it. Which is ridiculous.

Comment: It is a single backslash, it is just displayed to you as a double. Test this: `'\\'.bytes`. It will return `[92]`, a single byte, the ASCII code for a backslash. If you print it out, it will still show 2 backslashes, but it is one.

Comment: Thanks. This solves most of my issue and I will ask the remaining problem in another question.

Comment: Just because I dislike the parenthetical operation calls like this `(str <=> other).zero?`. I would recommend changing this to clear method calls e.g. `str.<=>(other).zero?` since the "spaceship" (`<=>`) is just a method.

Comment: My personal preference is the way I used it. I don't care for using operators following a dot like a method. Just appears strange to my eyes.

Comment: Your example is wrong. `puts a` shows `\ ` (and returns `nil`). `p a` would show `"\\"`

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Your comment about the newline character is incorrect though. In single quotes only backslash and single quotes can be escaped. The string `'\n'` would be a two character string of a backslash and the `n` character, not a newline. To use newline characters you have to use double quotes `"\n"`. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings

Comment: @JohanWentholt Tis, true. The elementary rule/use of single or double quoted strings wasn't really the point in the comment, I was simply trying to convey a point about storing a newline in a variable. But you are right, it would technically need to be double-quotes to work as desired. I assume OP knows the difference as well considering the liberal use in the examples.